# Can you factor quadratic equations where two variables are not divisible?

Tags: quadratics, factoring

The question is whether $9x^2+16y^2z^4$ can be factored. Many algebra calculators online are saying that they can't be factored whilst I think that we can factor it using the difference of two squares to solve it, can it be factored?

Thank you

Comment: So would that mean that this equation is not able to be factorised?

Comment: Factorization over which ring? over $\mathbb{R}$? it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$ since it is $(3x+4iyz^{2})(3x-4iyz^{2})$.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a difference of squares (at least with real numbers) thus it is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. Differences of squares come in the form $a^2 - b^2$, but $9x^2+16y^2z^4$ does not fit this form since it has a plus sign, not a minus sign.

But if you allow for imaginary numbers, you can do the following:

$$9x^2+16y^2z^4 = 9x^2-(-16y^2z^4)=(3x)^2-(4iyz^2)^2$$

Which gives you the following factors:

$$(3x-4iyz^2)(3x+4iyz^2)$$

Thus it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$. This gives you the two solutions hinted by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra given by the equation $9x^2+16y^2z^4 = 0$.

Comment: If the question were 9x^2-16y^2z^4, then would it be solvable?

Comment: @Sid Assuming you're referring *to the equation $9x^2-16y^2z^4=0$*, not the *expression* $9x^2-16y^2z^4$, **then it would be reducible over $\mathbb{R}$**. You'd get two real solutions. In its current form, you still get two solutions, just imaginary ones...